# Laravel data_get helper has different behavior for array and object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.6

```
$array = ['key' => null];

echo data_get($array, 'key', 'default') // Result was default
$array = (object) $array;
echo data_get($array, 'key', 'default') // Result was null
```

Is there any specific reason it was done like this or arrays and objects?

Laravel doc [ref](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-data-get) they mentioned like this `data_get function retrieves a value from a nested array or object using "dot" notation:` So it should be same behavior for both array and object

Answer (score 1):

If you check source of [`data_get()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L442), you'll notice

```
if (Arr::accessible($target) && Arr::exists($target, $segment)) {
    $target = $target[$segment];
} elseif (is_object($target) && isset($target->{$segment})) {
    $target = $target->{$segment};
} else {
    return value($default);
}
```

and `isset($target->{$segment})` which returns `false` for `null` and hence returns the default value for object which has `null` value for the searched key.

Comment: Yes i checked that source of data_get is there any specific reason they done like that but as per doc we can use this for both object and array